# WPF. How to set checkbox near the textblock field?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, material-design-in-xaml

I'm new in WPF and just want to set my checkbox field near my textblock not under it. How should I edit my xaml?

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical"
                                                Margin="{StaticResource LeftTopThickness}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource lang_SubscriberTreatment_Tariffs_PaperCopy}"
                                                  Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=PAPERCOPY_ID}" />
                                        <!--<TextBox x:Name="PAPERCOPY_ID" Text="{Binding PaperCopy}" />-->
                                        <CheckBox Name="PAPERCOPY_ID"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=PaperCopy,Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: `Orientation="Horizontal"` instead of  `Orientation="Vertical"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Orientation of `StackPanel` to `Horizontal` instead of `Vertical`:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="{StaticResource LeftTopThickness}">
     <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource lang_SubscriberTreatment_Tariffs_PaperCopy}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=PAPERCOPY_ID}" />
     <!--<TextBox x:Name="PAPERCOPY_ID" Text="{Binding PaperCopy}" />-->
     <CheckBox Name="PAPERCOPY_ID"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=PaperCopy,Mode=OneWay}" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
</StackPanel>
```